# INFORMATICA Traget Flat File. HOW TO align data to header

Tags: informatica

I have a pipe delimited file and want to find out how to align my informatica target data to header.

For example: Current output

`FullNameofPerson|ChangedNameofPerson`

`JohnDoe|JonDoe`

Wanted/Expected Output in txt flat file.

`FullNameofPerson|ChangedNameofPerson`

`JohnDoe         |JonDoe`

Comment: Looks like data has space in the end. so use `RTRIM(FullNameofPerson)` to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We can use padding to fill up the gaps after the data to align with header.
You can use
`out_FullNameofPerson= RPAD( FullNameofPerson, length('FullNameofPerson'),' ')` in an EXP to fix this issue for FullNameofPerson.
You have to modify all columns in this way.
And then attach this `out_FullNameofPerson` port to file target.
Also make sure  you are adding header to the output file.